# iTextSharp - footer on top of the PDF page issue

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext

I am working on an older project so the iTextSharp version is 3.1.7.0.
The header part is working just fine, but I have some issues with the footer. When I add only text, footer is showing where it should - at the bottom of the page. But when I add table instead of just text, footer jumps on top of the page. This is my code, what am I missing?

```
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 40, 0, 30);

PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase("Table Header"));
cell.Colspan = 3;
cell.HorizontalAlignment = 2;

table.AddCell(cell);
table.AddCell("Cell1example");
table.AddCell("Cell2example");
table.AddCell("Cell3example");
table.AddCell("Cell4example");
table.AddCell("Cell5example");
table.AddCell("Cell6example");

Phrase footerPhrase = new Phrase();
footerPhrase.Add(table);
footerPhrase.Leading = 10;

HeaderFooter footer = new HeaderFooter(footerPhrase, false);
document.Footer = footer;
```

Comment: iTextSharp 3.1.7.0 hasn't been supported anymore for many years. You shouldn't use the `HeaderFooter` class. Headers and footers are added using page events. See [footer examples and FAQs](http://developers.itextpdf.com/tags/footer).

Comment: I know but I'm stuck with it, at least for the current project. I can't find old examples on iText web site, any ideas what should I use in this version? And how?

Comment: Tables in `HeaderFooter` are not supported in that old version. You need to use page events. I don't know if page events were already supported in that old version. If not, you're out of luck.

Comment: But there is a table in my header and it is working fine :/.

Comment: It's working "by accident". In the old version of iTextSharp, one wasn't supposed to put a table inside a `Phrase`. Why don't you try page events?

Comment: I used `ColumnText` from your  [Example](http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/page-events/page-events-headers-and-footers) and it worked, thanks! :D.